# home.reports.product.compared block in default home page never displays

Tags: layout, blocks, cms, xml

I'm trying to use the layout XML that is set by default on the CMS Home page of a clean Magento install (See Admin > `CMS > Pages > Design tab > Layout Update XML`). It inserts three product blocks: new products, recently viewed products, and (I think) recently compared products.

All is well, except for the the recently compared block `home.reports.product.compared` which, despite my having compared some items (and they show up in the compare sidebar block), is never populated.

Am I misunderstanding the role of the block, or is it just plain broken?

Possibly related: the XML also unsets the sidebar blocks for recently viewed and compare, however the compare block still appears and in fact appears twice in the sidebar, only on the homepage.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
    <action method="setProductsCount"><count>8</count></action>
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
</block>
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">
    <action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action>
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
</block>
<block type="reports/product_compared" name="home.reports.product.compared" template="reports/home_product_compared.phtml" after="product_viewed">
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Impossible to know without seeing the actual XML you're using for the page.  I suggest you post it so people can actually help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience the recently compared items block will only display after removing the items from your compare list.

If you remove the items with the handy "clear all" or on a item basis from the compare side bar they should then appear on the bottom of the home page.